# Simplify Fibonacci Power Series

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, satisfiability

I am working on an algorithm to count the number of models for [Exactly One in Three SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-in-three_3SAT) (X3SAT) instances. It is known that a chain of X3SAT clauses of length $c$ has $F(c+3)$ satisfying assignments where $F(x)$ is the [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) series. A chain of length $c$ must have $2c+1$ distinct literals. Making some completely unwarranted assumptions about the number of disjoint chains of length $c$ that will "cover" an X3SAT instance I get the following relation:

$F(c+3)^k$ where $k=n/(2c+1)$

Can this function be simplified? Can it be rewritten in a form like $g(c)^n$?

Comment: $F_n \approx \dfrac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\varphi = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$